# Type arguments cannot be applied to non-paremterized class 'BFTask'

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am using parse and swift in Xcode 7. So I opened up one of my Xcode projects that I haven't used in a while and when I tried to run it I was met with 22 random errors when it had been working fine before. The error is: Type arguments cannot be applied to non-paremterized class 'BFTask' and these errors are coming from PFAnalytics.h and PFObject.h. I am also getting the error could not build module 'Parse' from my bridging header. What is wrong? Here is my Parse frameworks:[image]

And here are my errors:
[image]

Comment: Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this happens you must make sure that you are using the same exact frameworks that you downloaded and put in your project originally otherwise it is easy for the individual frameworks to have version issues. If for some reason you don't have all of the original frameworks then the other thing you can try is to go to parse.com and download new versions of all the frameworks delete the current ones in the project, and replace them with the ones you just downloaded.